# can't resolve framework issues

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am using a paytm frame work in my application and I need to update it on App Store however I can't do that with Xcode 10 as there is a sdk problem but when I upgraded to Xcode 11 the following issue occurred

`Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler`

some research and I changed some build settings like this

build library for distribution to yes

but now new error pops up like this

< unknown >:0: error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

please help I USE COCOAPODS